# Why is this independent random variable cannot deduce $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(Y)\mathbb{E}(Y)$

Tags: statistics, proof-explanation, expected-value, statistical-inference, estimation

[image]

Here is the proof of biased and unbiased sample variance. Since they are random sample they are i.i.d.

From the process of

$$\sum^n_{i=1}\mathbb{E}(Y^2_i)-n\mathbb{E}(\bar{Y}^2)$$

I was thinking about

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_i^2)=\mathbb{E}(Y_i)\mathbb{E}(Y_i)$$,similarly for $\mathbb{E}(\bar{Y}^2)$, why this is not the case?

Thank you for any comments

Book： *Mathematical Statistics with Applications*, Seventh Edition. Dennis D. Wackerly, William Mendenhall III, Richard L. Scheaffer.

Comment: I like this book, can you share the title?

Comment: $\mathbb E(Y_i^2)=\mathbb E(Y_i)\mathbb E(Y_i)$ would imply that $Y_i$ is independent of itself. But then, $Y_i$ would be almost surely a constant.

Comment: @PeterKeller Fabulous！！！